# What model should I use? Diff-in-Diff? Stata function?

Tags: regression, time-series, stata, difference-in-difference

I am looking at whether airlines entering into a merger has a positive or negative impact on profits. I have 4 airlines who have merged in the period 2005-2015 (including data pre-merger for both airlines that merge), and 6 airlines who have not merged (control group).

I am having difficulty working out what model to use, and how to implement a model into Stata. I know what I want to do, just can't do it! I was thinking of a diff-in-diff regression, but how would this work as the airlines do not all merge at the same time. In terms of variables to assess profitability of the airline pre/post merger, I have 6 variables that I would like to look at.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am at a complete dead-end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Notation:

$\pi^{pre, merged}_{t,j}$: pre-merger combined profit per time period of firm-pairs that merge before merging, where $j$ indexes the post-merger entity (j=1,2).

$\pi^{post, merged}_{t,j}$: post-merger profit per period of each entity.

$\pi^{control}_{t,j}$: profit per period for each control entity (j=1,2,3,4).

Combining the three expressions into a linear model gives:

$\pi_{t,j}=\pi^{control}_{t,j} + \pi^{pre, merged}_{t,j}+ \pi^{post, merged}_{t,j} \\
\pi_{i,j}=\beta_0 + \beta_1*Merged_{i} + \beta_2*Merged_{i}*PostMerge_{it} + \epsilon_{i,j}
$

$\beta_2$ is the D-n-D parameters that picks up the post-merging change in combined profit for merged entitites.

Data setup:

$Merge_i$ is a column of 1s for merged entities and a column of 0s for controls
$PostMerge_{it}$ is a time and entity-specific dummy. It is 1 for all merged entities after the date of merging and 0 otherwise.